# Access Autofilter listing with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How can I access the unique listing of values in the column that the autofilter displays with VBA?

I already know how to turn the autofilters on and off with VBA. I can access filters that the user has set with VBA. I can use VBA to set a filter if I know the value(s) to set.

I know how to get a unique listing of values from a column by copying the range and using Remove Duplicates. I can also use Advanced Filters to get a unique listing. I can create a unique listing by looping through all of the values and creating a collection or dictionary.

Comment: As @Jeeped stated, VBA cannot access the autofilter drop-down. You already know how to create a list of the unique values, so how does the autofilter list fit into this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the list sown in the worksheet's filter dropdown. Build a variant array of values based upon criteria instead and pass that array into the `.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(myArray), Operator:=xlFilterValues`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As stated previously, "I can use VBA to set a filter if I know the value(s) to set."